# Download or Access to SharePoint Online Documents using PHP / XML / SOAP

Tags: php, xml, sharepoint, soap, token

I am working on a web project that involves connecting to SharePoint Online via PHP and accessing the files stored on it. But I am extremely new to all this, and have hit a wall.

- I have the URL of the file I'm trying to access
- Using the [phpSPO library](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO), I am authenticated and connected to SharePoint.

The question is: how do I actually access the URL? If I follow the link directly, it redirects me to the login page for SharePoint. But we want the login to happen "behind the scenes" - and apparently the authentication step doesn't quite do that.

The company we are working with told us that we would need to request an anonymous link for the URL by calling a function. Problem is, the function they told us to use works in ASPX, but doesn't appear to be available in PHP.

This is the code they pointed us to:

```
Uri siteUri = new Uri(siteUrl);
Web web = context.Web;
SecureString passWord = new Secure String();
foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray())
    passWord.AppendChar(c);
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("userid", passWord);
WebDocs.Parameter1 = "123456"
WebDocs.Parameter2 = "Test"
context.Web.CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument(WebDocs.Parameter1, WebDocs.Parameter2, ExternalSharingDocumentOption.View);
```

But how can I translate that into PHP? Can I even do that?

And if not, is there another way that I can access the file to display it to my user?

```
// this says the function CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument doesn't exist
function getLink(ClientContext $ctx) {
    $anonymousLink = $ctx->getWeb()->CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument(); 
    $ctx->load($anonymousLink);
    $ctx->executeQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after hours and hours of searching the Internet....

The answer was right in front of my nose.

Started browsing through the examples/SharePoint/file_examples.php that came with the phpSPO library, and discovered 2 functions (either one works).

One is called downloadFile, and the other is downloadFileAsStream.

```
function downloadFile(ClientRuntimeContext $ctx, $fileUrl, $targetFilePath){
    $fileContent = 
Office365\PHP\Client\SharePoint\File::openBinary($ctx,$fileUrl);
    file_put_contents($targetFilePath, $fileContent);
    print "File {$fileUrl} has been downloaded successfully\r\n";
}

function downloadFileAsStream(ClientRuntimeContext $ctx, $fileUrl, 
    $targetFilePath) {
    $fileUrl = rawurlencode($fileUrl);

    $fp = fopen($targetFilePath, 'w+');
    $url = $ctx->getServiceRootUrl() . "web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('$fileUrl')/\$value";
    $options = new \Office365\PHP\Client\Runtime\Utilities\RequestOptions($url);
    $options->StreamHandle = $fp;
    $ctx->executeQueryDirect($options);
    fclose($fp);

    print "File {$fileUrl} has been downloaded successfully\r\n";
}
```

Since I was trying to download a PDF, I just set these functions to create a PDF on our own server.... and it works beautifully!!!!!